# Print Sql query in Symfony

Tags: mysql, symfony

I need to findout the normal sql query for the below. Can you guys please suggest me how can i achieve in Symfony.

Example:

```
 $r = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.worked_hours')
     ->from('tasksComments u')
     ->where('u.tasks_id = ?', $arr_values['tasks_id'])
     ->andwhere('u.id != ?', $arr_values['id'])
     ->andwhere('u.created_at LIKE ?', $date."%");
$results1 = $r->execute();
```

Answer (score 7):

On the query object, use the method `getSQL`.

In your case:

```
$r = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->select('u.worked_hours')
        ->from('tasksComments u')
        ->where('u.tasks_id = ?', $arr_values['tasks_id'])
        ->andwhere('u.id != ?', $arr_values['id'])
        ->andwhere('u.created_at LIKE ?', $date."%");

var_dump($r->getSQL()); // print the SQL query - you will need to replace the parameters in the query
var_dump($r->getParams()); // print the parameters of the query so you can easily replace the missing parameters in the query
```

Note that I don't know the namespace of `Doctrine_Query` but I am assuming that your `Query` object in this [Query object in the Doctrine API documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Query.html).

Comment: Thomas, Sorry to say I am getting error.**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine_Query::getSQL()**

Comment: Searching for the `Doctrine_Query` on Google doesn't return any results so it's quite hard to figure out why. Few things, can you find the file that holds the `Doctrine_Query` and let me know if there is a method `getQuery`? You tagged your answer with Symfony2, did you use the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) as a reference (I don't think you did)? What is the namespace of `Doctrine_Query` (should be declared at the top of the PHP file)?

Comment: Sorry,how can i get full SQL string ,replaced `?` with the corresponding parameters  after `$r->getSqlQuery();` ?

Answer (score 3):

Using Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine 1.2.3

`echo $q->getSqlQuery()`;

Answer (score 0):

You can view all the executed queries in the profiler toolbar by clicking on the db panel icon (the last section of the toolbar) then on the *[Display runnable query]* link under your query.